# How to run an entire Jupyter Notebook in debug mode using the Jupyter Extension in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-debugger

**Status quo:**

According to the [official documentation of VS-Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_debug-a-jupyter-notebook) there are currently 2 debug modes supported:

1. single line
2. single cell

**Issue:**

*Yet, there is apparently no way of running the entire Notebook in debug mode.*
This would be very useful since more often than not one does not know in which cell an error might occur.

**Current suboptimal workflow:**

I have to run the entire Notebook in normal execution mode and when it
fails within a certain cell, I have to rerun said cell in debug mode.

**Feature request:**

Provide a 3rd debug mode: allow for running the entire notebook in debug mode. Otherwise, a workaround like running the notebook from the CLI or some other approach would be much appreciated.